# gRPC Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, windows-10, grpc

I was trying to test gRPC server and client on two different machines and made sure the firewall rules are enabled (both inbound & outbound ) and verified the connectivity.

```
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.20.51904
.NET Version: 5.0.0
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10.110.127.139:5001) SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10.110.111.129:5001)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamWriter`2.WriteAsyncCore[TState](Func`5 writeFunc, TState state)
   at Sender.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\fileshare-using-dotnet-grpc-master\Sender\Program.cs:line 56
   at Sender.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: `UNAVAILABLE` error generally means that your server is not up or that the client can't access it. We do not have much information about your setup here, so can't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically is error code 14(UNAVAILABLE):

See more:
https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html

The most common case is if you call a nonexistent server. So please call it from the local server first, and make sure the server is working.